# How to send POST request with multipart/form-data using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I've asked something like that before, but here are slightly different cases and more details.

I have a handler on the server side which is accepting multipart/form-data POST requests. Request contains number of POST parameters and one more parameter which should contain image file (this last parameter may exist or may not exist). How to send such requests using angularJS?

I've tried number of options (all of them for know without file uploading) but none of them works. I'm getting wrong result because absence of Content-Type: multipart/form-data in the HTTP request, or getting exception from Jetty-based Spark web-services tool (pleas don't confuse with Apache Spark) which sounds like "..."Missing initial multi part boundary..." - depending on the request details.

I've tried this:

```
return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: editCompanyUrl,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
            data: {
                token: token,
                userId: userId,
                companyId: companyId,
                companyName: $scope.companyName,
            },
            timeout: 500
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //Store Company ID which is used for saving purposes
            //localStorage.setItem("companyId", data.data.Company.id);
            return data.data.Company;
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
```

and this for example

```
return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: editCompanyUrl,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            data: {
                token: token,
                userId: userId,
                companyId: companyId,
                companyName: $scope.companyName,
            },
            timeout: 500
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //Store Company ID which is used for saving purposes
            //localStorage.setItem("companyId", data.data.Company.id);
            return data.data.Company;
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
```

Could you please help? What is the right way to send multipart requests?

Thank you.

Kind regards, Artem.

Answer (score 0):

$http provides an option : **params**.

Use **params:** instead of **data:**

```
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            params: {
             token: token,
             userId: userId,
             companyId: companyId,
             companyName: $scope.companyName,
           },
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //SUCCESS
          }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //ERROR
       });
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas! Thank you for the answer, but how to add support of multipart/form-data? And sometimes (depending on code variations) there is an additional OPTIONS request before POST (as far as I understand it is related to CORS) - how to avoid it? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @ArtemVorobyev, first, is it working now ? And then, OPTIONS is is how Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard mandates browsers to behave, it's not a Bug :) ! What would you want to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the complete error. And also your server side code. To get multi part content in Spark, you have to use this at your server side:

```
  MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement("Yourstoragedirectory");
  request.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", multipartConfigElement);
  System.out.println(request.raw().getPart("file"));
```

Also make sure you have the latest version of spark.